# ASIHTTPRequest File Upload and PHP

Tags: php, iphone, asihttprequest

I am using the following code (with ASIHTTPRequest) to attempt to upload php files from my iPhone to my LAN MAMP server running on my Macbook Pro.  My objective-c and my php seem to be in line, but the files are not uploading.

OBJECTIVE-C CODE

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[pieces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.102:8888/upload.php"];


ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setFile:path forKey:@"file"];
```

PHP CODE

```
 <?php
$target = "uploads/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;
$ok=1;
(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target));
?>
```

What is going wrong here?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Sorry, I'm not uploading PHP files, I'm uploading CSV files, for what its worth.  I am, however, using PHP on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Apache httpd process have the privileges to write in the `uploads/` directory? Try setting it to `/tmp/` and see if that works?

I created a backup solution for [AppSales-Mobile](http://github.com/epatel/AppSales-Mobile) using a small php script. Wrote about it [here](http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/11/22/Lightweight-backup.html). The php script I created looks like [this](http://github.com/epatel/AppSales-Mobile/blob/master/upload_appsales.php). The actual post code can be viewed [here](http://github.com/epatel/AppSales-Mobile/blob/master/Classes/ReportManager.m#L568) in the method `- (void) startUpload`.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode**

```
[request setFile:path forKey:@"myfile"];
```

**php**

```
$uploaddir = '';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);


move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. Are you sure your server's PHP configuration is accepting uploads, and that the CSVs are within the size limitation?

Answer (score 0):

I know this response is probably too late to help you specifically but just in case other people have the same problem and view this post, I found the solution. I was having this exact problem and none of the examples I could find seemed to include the solution. But it's quite simple, you have to "start" the upload, just as you do with the downloads.

In short, at the end of your objective-c code, you would add the line:

```
[request startSynchronous];
```